# Android AVD the "ok" button is disabled

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create a new virtual device using my AVD. But the Ok button is always disabled and so I'm unable to create a new one.[image]

Can anyone please help me in this issue????

Comment: I've all the things properly installed in my SDK up-to-date.

Comment: Alaas... The problem is solved for me, just by restarting the eclipse. Thank you all for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CPU/ABI - No system images installed for this Target.

This tells everything. Get the images `ARM EABI v7a System Image` through Android SDK Manager for that specific Target.

[image]

**TIP :**

1. Restart `eclipse` once you installed the image.
2. Your avd name should not contain space like `Demo emulator`. It should be `demoemulator`.

Comment: All those where installed exactly in my sdk, I just tried restarting Eclipse and it worked. Thank you all for your responses.